# How does the Kotlin compiler decide whether a suspend method may be called at any given point?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

Kotlin coroutines define `delay` as a suspending function with the `suspend` keyword, so

- Calling `delay` as a direct child statement of `main` is not
  allowed, because `main` is not a suspending function
- Calling `delay` as a child of `runBlocking` or `launch` is allowed, because those
  functions create a coroutine scope.

How does the compiler know this? The `suspend` keyword is part of the language proper, whereas `runBlocking`, `launch`, and the concept of couroutine scopes are added via the `kotlinx.couroutines` library. Since the syntax check outlined above presumably does not depend on that specific implementation, how does it work?

Comment: If you look at [runBlocking](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html) and [launch](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html), you'll see the higher-order function parameter (what let's you use a lambda with those functions) is marked `suspend`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remember in most cases if we create a new "scope" or "block" of code, so we use `{ ... }`, for example:

```kotlin
listOf(1).forEach { ... }
runCatching { ... }
run { ... }
```

Then technically speaking, we call a function passing a lambda to it. The function we call specifies what is the type of the lambda we pass. For example, `runCatching()` is defined as:

```kotlin
public inline fun <R> runCatching(block: () -> R): Result<R> {
```

Now, let's see the `runBlocking()`:

```kotlin
public actual fun <T> runBlocking(context: CoroutineContext, block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T): T {
```

Do you see a difference in the `block` parameter? It is marked as `suspend`. That means `runBlocking()` expects we pass a suspending lambda to it, so the compiler can know we are in a suspending context.

Please read for more information: [Higher-order functions and lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html)